# Adding octal bit to PHP's mkdir from .env variable

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I have an issue that when I try to load a permission string from my .env file in Laravel and then when I try to use it as an int for the file mode arg in `mkdir` it deletes the octal bit `0` and as a result the `mkdir` call gets messed up:

`mkdir($this->bakDir, 0755);`

Works fine.

`echo(\Config::get('app.dbBackupDirPerms'));`
`echo(intval(\Config::get('app.dbBackupDirPerms')));`

`mkdir($this->bakDir, intval(\Config::get('app.dbBackupDirPerms')));`

> 0755
>
> 755
>
> Creates the directory but with the incorrect permissions

Passing `\Config::get('app.dbBackupDirPerms');` as a string also doesn't work to my surprise, I figured it would not be type checked by `mkdir`

Is there anyway around this, am I missing something here? Relatively new to PHP, but I imagine this must be a relatively common occurrence.

Comment: Read about [`intval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to convert your int to octal

```
mkdir($this->bakDir, intval(\Config::get('app.dbBackupDirPerms'), 8 ));
```